# Hide error messages in GRUB

Tags: grub

How to hide error messages in GRUB? I have this setting in GRUB config, but I still see two log error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Kernel Admin Guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) specifies that the option `quiet` disables "most" log messages. You may have to use the `loglevel=0` parameter in addition, as suggested [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `loglevel` kernel parameter:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=0 splash"
```